# Dimension mismatch in keras layers

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a small CNN+RNN network as follows.

```
batch_size=2048


visible = Input(shape=(batch_size,251))

embed=Embedding(58, 50)(visible)
x1=keras.layers.Conv1D(92,50,activation='relu')(embed)
x2=keras.layers.GRU(224, return_sequences=True)(x1)

x3=keras.layers.GRU(284)(x2)

predictions=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x3)
```

How can I make the dimensional compatibility suitable between different layers. I am getting the following error just by running this piece of code.

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_4: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the input shape as follows.

```
visible = Input(shape=(251,))
```